# Creating in C code that outputs the number of words, number of distinct words, and most frequent word

Tags: c

I need to write code that reads a text file and outputs the number of words, number of distinct words, and the most frequent word in C.

I have already done the code for outputting the number of words, but I have no idea how to find the number of distinct words or the most frequent word. I know I'm supposed to use strcmp, but I don't know about doing so. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's what I have so far.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int number=0;
    char temp[25000][50];
    char word[25000][50];
    char *word2[25000][50];
    int wordCount=0;
    int distinctCount=0;
    FILE *fp;

    //reads file!
    fp = fopen("COEN12_LAB1.txt", "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File Missing!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //counts words in file!
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s", word) == 1)
        wordCount++;

    printf("Total number of words: %d\n", wordCount);
    fclose(fp);`
}
```

Comment: Some kind of map data structure would be the best solution, in the absence of that, you're going to need an `int` array the same size as your `word` array, and every time you read a new word, you'll have to cycle through the `word` array and check each one with `strcmp()` to see if you've already found it. If not, add a new word. If so, increment the respective element in the `int` array by 1. This is obviously a massively inefficient method.

Comment: That is a lot of automatic storage you are allocating there.

Comment: Look up and read about fgets() and strtok() for reading the file and parsing lines into strings (words).  Then read about strstr() and strcmp() to begin comparing and counting unique strings into categories.  Then you can consider what happens if some wise ass puts a word bigger than 49 characters into your file.  (may also want to read up on char *string;, calloc() and realloc() and free() functions.)

Comment: `cat "Last summer I went to Llanfairpwllgwyngychgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch on my vacation." >> COEN12_LAB1.txt`

Comment: I would just sort the array of words, then you can go word by word... if(strcmp(current,last)){++distinct;if(curr_cnt>max)most=current;curr_cnt=1}else ++curr_cnt;`

Answer (score 1):

First you probably need to implement structure that will allow you to efficiently keep distinct words. [Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is one of the possible ones (maybe best).

Here is example of implementation and usage of hashes on C:

- http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/index.html
- http://elliottback.com/wp/hashmap-implementation-in-c/

Also you can look into this question: [Porting std::map to C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647054/porting-stdmap-to-c)

Comment: You can also use Gnomes glib, it has a nice hash implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote program for you, see source here: http://olegh.cc.st/src/words.c.txt
Of course, did not check special situations, like many words on single line,
distinct words qty > 16,000, etc. But, basic code you can get:

Run sample:

```
$ cat aaa.txt
aaa
bbb
ccc
aaa
xxx
aaa
cc

$ cc words.c ; ./a.out aaa.txt
   1    xxx
   1    ccc
   1    bbb
   1    cc
   3    aaa
```

Comment: I input a short text file (3 lines, about 25 or so words) but it only output ***Words = 3 Distinct = 3 Frequent = n...***.  The OP is asking to read a text file which will usually have variations of common punctuation and some unprintable characters such as `\n`, `\t`, etc.  Your line `while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f))` I think is reading (as it should) and entire line, made up of several words and some punctuation.  If you account for that, I think your program will be a step further.

Answer (score 0):

***[EDIT]***
*1. replaced malloc with calloc (initializes memory to 0)*
*2. replaced second argument in qsort*
*3. program now works with wider range of files (more words, more delimiters)*

This is not pretty, and may need some minor debug, but it will get you started for count, number of distinct and most frequently used words:

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILENAME "c:\\dev\\play\\test3.txt" //put your own path here
#define DELIM "- .,:;//_*&\n"

int longestWord(char *file, int *cnt);
void allocMemory(int numStrings, int max);
void freeMemory(int numStrings);

static int sortstring( const void *str1, const void *str2 );

char **strings;

int main()
{
    int wc, longest, cnt, distinct, i, mostFreq, mostFreqKeep=0;
    char line[260];
    char *buf=0;
    FILE *fp;

    longest = longestWord(FILENAME, &wc);

    char wordKeep[longest];
    allocMemory(wc, longest);

    //read file into string arrays 
    fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
    cnt=0;
    while(fgets(line, 260, fp))
    {
        buf = strtok(line, DELIM);
        while(buf)  
        {
            if((strlen(buf) > 0) && (buf[0] != '\t') && (buf[0] != '\n') && (buf[0] != '\0')&& (buf[0] > 0))
            {
                strcpy(strings[cnt], buf);
                cnt++; //use as accurate count of words.
            }
            buf = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    //now get most frequent word
    //sort
    qsort(strings, cnt, sizeof(char*), sortstring);
    distinct = 1;
    mostFreq = 1; //every word will occur once
    wordKeep[0]=0;
    for(i=0;i<cnt-1;i++)
    {
        //depends on a successful sort (alphabetization)
        if(strlen(strings[i]) >0)
        {
            if(strcmp(strings[i], strings[i+1]) == 0)
            {
                mostFreq++;
                if(mostFreq > mostFreqKeep) 
                {
                    strcpy(wordKeep, strings[i]);
                    mostFreqKeep = mostFreq;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mostFreq = 1;
                distinct++; 
            }
        }
    }
    printf("number of words: %d\nNumber of distinct words:%d\nmost frequent word: %s - %d\n", cnt, distinct, wordKeep, mostFreqKeep);

    freeMemory(cnt);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int longestWord(char *file, int *nWords)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int cnt=0, longest=0, numWords=0;
    char c;
    fp = fopen(file, "r");
    while ( (c = fgetc ( fp) ) != EOF )
    {
        if ( isalpha ( c ) ) cnt++;
        else if ( ( ispunct ( c ) ) || ( isspace ( c ) ) )
        {
            (cnt > longest) ? (longest = cnt, cnt=0) : (cnt=0);
            numWords++;
        }
    }
    *nWords = numWords;
    fclose(fp);
    return longest+1;
}

void allocMemory(int numStrings, int max)
{
    int i;
    strings = calloc(sizeof(char*)*(numStrings+1), sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
    {
      strings[i] = calloc(sizeof(char)*max + 1, sizeof(char));
    }
}

void freeMemory(int numStrings)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
        if(strings[i]) free(strings[i]);
    free(strings);  
}

static int sortstring( const void *str1, const void *str2 )
{
    const char *rec1 = *(const char**)str1;
    const char *rec2 = *(const char**)str2;
    int val = strcmp(rec1, rec2);

    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple database to compute the different word counts from the input text. For simplicity I'd suggest to use [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sqlite). Below I have added some example code (I left out the error handling for the sake of brevity).

For reading words I took an approach to read a single line into a buffer using `fgets`. I noticed that this approach works nicely as long you can guarantee that the buffer is always large enough to hold the actual lines from the input file. Otherwise words are split up at the end of the buffer, which needs to be handled somehow.

For parsing the text I have used `strtok`. During the implementation I have learned that it's quite hard to get the word-delimiters right. Besides this, possible spelling differences (e.g., capitalization) and [inflections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection) of otherwise equal words are completely ignored by this approach and could thus negatively affect the result.

Once the data is in the database, the query language is very well suited to formulate queries to get the maximum (distinct) word count, or word frequencies. Therefore I think this flexible approach has an advantage when you want to compute multiple statistics from the input text, as you don't have to implement every special case in C. For testing, I copied a [part of the Wikipedia article on SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sqlite#Features) into the file `words.txt`.

Here's the example:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DELIM " \r\n\t,.-;:_#+*\\=)(/&%$§\"“”!1234567890}][{'"
#define BUFSIZE 4096
#define SQLSIZE 256

int print_row(void* p, int ncols, char **values, char **names) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ncols; i++)
        printf("| %15s : %15s %s", names[i], values[i], i<ncols-1?"":"|\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    /* open infile */
    FILE * infile = fopen("words.txt", "r");
    /* initialize database */
    sqlite3 *db_handle = 0;
    sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db_handle);
    sqlite3_exec(db_handle, "CREATE TABLE word (word TEXT);", 0, 0, 0);
    /* parse file, populate db */
    char buf[BUFSIZE], sql[SQLSIZE], *word;
    while(fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, infile))
        for (word = strtok(buf, DELIM); word != 0; word = strtok(0, DELIM)) {
            snprintf(sql, SQLSIZE, "INSERT INTO word VALUES ('%s');", word);
            sqlite3_exec(db_handle, sql, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    /* count of words */
    sqlite3_exec(db_handle,
                 "SELECT COUNT(word) AS total_words FROM word;",
                 print_row, 0, 0);
    /* count of distinct words */
    sqlite3_exec(db_handle,
                 "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT word) AS distinct_words FROM word;",
                 print_row, 0, 0);
    /* top five most frequent words */
    sqlite3_exec(db_handle,
                 "SELECT word, COUNT(*) AS count FROM word "
                 "GROUP BY word ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5;",
                 print_row, 0, 0);
    sqlite3_close(db_handle);
}
```

Here's my output:

```
$ gcc test.c -std=c99 -lsqlite3 && ./a.out 
|     total_words :             561 |
|  distinct_words :             314 |
|            word :          SQLite |           count :              17 |
|            word :              is |           count :              16 |
|            word :             the |           count :              15 |
|            word :               a |           count :              14 |
|            word :              to |           count :              12 |
```

For reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf
- http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html
- http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html
- http://sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html
- http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html
- http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html
- http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html
- http://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html