# How to use C++ maps in C programming?

Tags: c, dictionary, key-value, stdmap, std

*I have a C program, in which I want to store Key value pair of 2 strings.

I know we can use `std::map` in C++.

I want to know is there a way I can use`std::map` in C or is there any other substitute for storing data similar to it in C.*

Comment: You can create a wrapper around the C++ maps and link it with your c code. Won't have templates though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647054/porting-stdmap-to-c

Comment: http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/index.html maybe something for you